# Dimmer for electric underfloor heating element

Tags: current, switches, control, industrial

I'm new here and a mechanical engineer who knows just a little about electronics, so please excuse any ignorance.

We have electric underfloor heating in our kitchen. It seems the thermostatic probe under the floor has developed a fault. I can't change it as the stone floor cost many '000s to lay!

The heating element appears fine and has a resistance of 40ohms. I figure on a 240v circuit this draws 6A, 1440W.
I am able to connect the element directly to the supply and it works fine, however as the thermo probe is faulty it is either on or off via a wall switch.

What I would ideally like to do is replace the wall switch with a dimmer switch similar to a lighting dimmer. These at a retail level appear to be 240v/400W/1.6A.

How can I create a dimmer which will work with 6A? Or is there an industrial version I could use?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You don't need a dimmer. You want variable duty-cycle on-off control. See http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/ for a little introduction (by me) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I create a dimmer which will work with 6A?*

It's probably not a great idea to use any type of light dimmer topology because they switch the AC waveform on with fast edges and, given that your load is a distributed series of heating elements (i.e. it has a large magnetic loop-area), you might cause high-frequency disturbances that cause radios not to work i.e. they'll pick up a lot of interference (and maybe your neighbours radio as well).

The thermal inertia of your heating system will be large so, instead, use a timer type circuit that switches the AC on for a minute then off for a minute etc.. You should be able to find some circuits that do this based on a 555 timer and an AC relay.

Comment: Even better, the switch can be a SSR with zero voltage switching to avoid the sparking and RF interference from a relay.

Answer (score 0):

> We have electric underfloor heating in our kitchen. It seems the thermostatic probe under the floor has developed a fault.

Check your temperature probe. If I had to put one of these in poured concrete, I'd insert it into a conduit, to be able to pull it out later to replace it. Maybe this is the case?

Or... maybe the probe works, but the circuit inside the thermostat is dead. Have you investigated this? You could simply measure the probe with a multimeter on "ohms" setting. If it has two wires, it's probably a thermistor. If you get a resistance value that is neither "short circuit" nor "open" then it's probably okay.

Now, if the probe works, then you have to fix the thermostat.

But if the thermostat works, and the probe is really dead, then you could put another probe hidden under the kitchen cabinets, stuck on the floor with adhesive tape. It will probably have a bit longer reaction time than a probe inside the floor, but it's still better than a dead probe.

If you can't buy a new probe, you could also replace the thermostat with one that comes with a probe, again hidden under the kitchen cabinets. That would preserve the temperature regulation, which would be more convenient than just a dimmer.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answer says, if you use a standard dimmer with triacs, may be you have to filter with a inductor + capacitor to avoid radio interferences. Other proposals you have to work with several modules to link.
There is a very simple way to reduce 50 % of the power: a series diode. Choose one of  reverse voltage 400 V or more, and 6 amperes (current should be 3 amp). If you need full heating, bypass this diode with a switch. You will not have regulation, but may be with these 2 steps you can live.